# RedirectMatch /blog/?(something) to /?(something)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all requests which have "/blog/?" to "/?..." and use the following in my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /blog/?(.*) http://www.example.com/?$1
```

but when I check it,

```
/blog/?p=28  -> www.example.com/?
```

so the rest is truncated.

p/s/ I don't want to redirect /blog/(something) to example.com/(something) !

p/p/s/ I have a wordpress installed, if that might matter. And I need to do that kind of stuff because I changed my wordpress folder to root and use /blog/ to show recent posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your .htaccess to achieve that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ / [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: what that "QSA" means? (L - last rule)

Comment: QSA - Query String Append, R - Redirect, L - Last. Please check this Apache Manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html for all the flags.

Answer (score 0):

try this code `.htacess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /





RewriteRule ^ProductView-(.*).html product.php?page=$1



RewriteRule ^Home.html index.php
```

put your file name like this and change`enter code here`